# Stroke a shape without making it bigger (AI or CorelDraw)

Tags: vector-graphics, adobe-illustrator, coreldraw

Is there a way in Illustrator or in CorelDraw to stroke multiple shapes and keep the current distance between them? Or to stroke them without making them bigger?

I have a map with a lot of shapes and I have to stroke them all, but since the stroking is 50:50 and the shapes are very close to each other I will have to reposition all of them (and this means repostioning of more than 150 shapes, I do not know the exact count; the trickiest part is that since they represent a map they have so many edges that have to fit -repositioning them one by one will be a nightmare).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shapes are closed paths, you can align a stroke to the inside. More information on the [adobe help page.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WSA1E31D7D-13E6-41ac-AA8C-4AD129B9FC1Ca.html#WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6511a)

Answer (score 0):

CorelDraw script:

```
Sub BoxInset()
Optimization = True
Set d = ActiveDocument
d.BeginCommandGroup "Box Inset"
For Each sl In ActiveSelection.Shapes
    With sl
        ow# = .Outline.Width
        .GetSize x#, y#
        .SetSize x - ow, y - ow
        .Move ow / 2, -ow / 2
    End With
Next
d.EndCommandGroup: Optimization = False: ActiveWindow.Refresh
End Sub
```